# How to check for extra parameters in ash script?

Tags: parsing, getopts, ash

I have an ash script where I need to check whether the user has entered anything stupid. The proper use is:

```
script <read | monitor> -s <system | event> [-f filter] [-n number]
```

And I need to detect if user has for example evoked it like:

```
script read -s system dummydummy
```

In order to parse the proper arguments, I use

```
while getopts "s:f:n:" Option
do
  case $Option in
    s)logname=${OPTARG};;
    f)filterspec=${OPTARG};;
    n)numlines=${OPTARG};;
    *)exit $E_OPTERROR;;   # DEFAULT
  esac
  OPRIND=${OPTIND}
done
```

How can I detect if there are any leftover unparsed arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this after exiting the *while*-loop:

```
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
echo "Remaining arguments: $@"
```

It works in *bash*-like shells, let us know if it works in ash too.